# Different db for testing in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, sqlite, postgresql

```
DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'postgresql_psycopg2',
#        ...
#    }

    # for unit tests
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase'
    }
}
```

I have two databases: one I'd like to use for unit tests, and one for everything else. Is it possible to configure this in Django 1.2.4?

(The reason I ask is because with postgresql I'm getting the following error:

```
foo@bar:~/path/$ python manage.py test
Creating test database 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_baz', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database...
Got an error recreating the test database: database "test_baz" does not exist
```

Why could I be getting this error? I guess I don't really care if I can always use SQLite for unit tests, as that works fine.)

Comment: Have you tried whether really the postgres user has database creation rights?

Comment: That postgres user works for browsing the site normally, but I guess I'm not sure if it can create the db.

Comment: Like @CarlesBarrobés said, it's you probably don't have CREAETE permissions. This comes straight from django's documentation: Note that to use this feature, the database user Django is connecting as must have CREATE DATABASE rights.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In your `settings.py` (or `local_settings.py`):

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase'
    }
```

Comment: @Rosarch...  yes; it is a bit "hacky", but you are right!  It works. :) But, IMHO, having to have any database for *UNIT* testing is hackish.  I wish Django had a different philosophy when it came to this.

Comment: @sleepycal Why is that?

Comment: I am trying to use this solution but I want to use **Postgres** as test database engine, and I get an error saying that tables don't exist. I thought test created the database. Is it so?

Comment: @HuLuViCa are you using managed or unmanaged models? are you using a runner script?

Comment: @DavidS then you are completely wrong. It IS the right approach to not do unit testing on actual data from your production database, that is not what unit tests are done for. Django essentially has the best approach here, not only that, it even takes care of that headache for the developer. People who want best practice for unit testing wants to use a different database for testing so it doesn't affect the original database in any way, specially if you need APIs for POST/PUT.

Answer (score 48):

The way I handle this is through having multiple settings files, since I use that to maintain a set of common settings with modifications for each instance.  It's a little more complicated to set up than some of the other solutions, but I needed to do it anyway because I was managing slightly different settings for local development, remote development, staging and production.

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings has a number of options for managing settings, and I've chosen a practice similar to the one described at https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SimplePackageOrganizationforEnvironments

So, in my Django project directory, I have a settings folder that looks like this:

```
$ tree settings
settings
├── defaults.py
├── dev.py
├── dev.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── lettuce.py
├── travis.py
├── unittest.py
```

The common settings are in settings/defaults.py and I import these in my instance settings files.  So settings/unittest.py looks like this:

```
from defaults import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'my_database',
    }
}
```

Then, when I want to run tests, I just execute:

```
$ ./manage.py test --settings=settings.unittest
```

to use sqlite for testing.  I'll use a different settings module if I want to use a different test runner or database configuration.

Comment: As one with a Rails background, I found this answer to be the best. Rails uses the same kind of convention, with the slight difference that in Rails the settings directory is named config.

Answer (score 32):

You can specify test database in `settings.py`. See
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'mytestdatabase',
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: this was a simple solution that worked perfectly. I am using the pythonanywhere website and this allowed me to run the tutorial.

Comment: Does this allow me to change the engine?

Comment: @Zee Yes, you can change everything I think. Check the docs for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: This allowed me to locate the test database when testing with the `--keepdb` argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't change the `HOST`.

Comment: This works, but note that the `default` still has to resolve. For example, if the URL of the database isn't resolvable when tests run, tests will crash.

Comment: @Lantern You cannot switch the engine nor the most of the other settings.

Comment: As of Django 3.1 , It cannot change database user credential `USER` and `PASSWORD`.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this issue simply creating other settings constant `DATABASES_AVAILABLE`.

```
DATABASES_AVAILABLE = {
    'main': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'nep',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'passwd',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    },
    'remote': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'nes_dev',
        'USER': 'usr',
        'PASSWORD': 'passwd',
        'HOST': '200.144.254.136',
    },
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
}

# This solves the problem with tests
# Define a system variable called DJANGO_DATABASE_TEST and set it to the
# the database you want
database = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DATABASE_TEST', 'main')
DATABASES = {
    'default': DATABASES_AVAILABLE[database]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This accelerated dramatically test execution.

```
import sys

if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'TEST_CHARSET': 'UTF8', # if your normal db is utf8
        'NAME': ':memory:', # in memory
        'TEST_NAME': ':memory:', # in memory
    }

    DEBUG = False # might accelerate a bit
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

    from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command('syncdb', migrate=True) # tables don't get created automatically for me
```

Answer (score 5):

Though this is already solved...

If your database for tests is just a normal DB:

I think you are not doing unit test since you rely in the database. Anyway, django contains a test type for that (not unitary): `django.test.TestCase`

You need to derive from `django.test.TestCase` instead of `unittest.TestCase` that will create a fresh rehershal database for you that will be destroyed when the test end.

There are interesting explanations/tips about testing with db in the following link
[Testing Django Applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/)

Comment: The problem I sometimes run into is when live data is fairly complex and came from some external source.  For testing I want a subset.  Yes I could create that subset is my test class setup.  But it can be non-trivial.  I especially find it better if my tests are read-only as far as the DB is concerned.

Comment: You then will potentially have non reproducible test :$ and running your tests will require connection to the open world

Answer (score 4):

You can mirror your db by editing `settings.py`:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'TEST': {
            'MIRROR': 'default',
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not only for this question but for most questions concerning performing unit tests that involve database access in Django. Today I spent 5 hours googling and reading so many blog posts. They were all hacky and obscure. This is the only one which is really Pythonic, leverages Django's default settings and covers most use cases. Thanks @ForeverOpp

Comment: Is the mirror a copy of the database with data, or an empty database with a copy of the schema?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to manually create the database, you could use [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) as your TEST_RUNNER. Once installed, if you pass the following environment variable, it will not delete and re-create the database.

```
REUSE_DB=1 ./manage.py test
```

You can also add the following to settings.py so you don't have to write REUSE_DB=1 every time you want to run tests:

```
os.environ['REUSE_DB'] = "1"
```

**Note:** this will also leave all your tables in the databases which means test setup will be a little quicker, but **you will have to manually update the tables** (or delete and re-create the database yourself) when you change your models.

Answer (score 2):

I had your same issue. I resolved it just adding in `settings.py` the TEST value in the database, available in my Django version 4.0.2, in this way:

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'HOST': host,
            'NAME': name,
            'TEST': {'NAME': 'test_db'},
            'USER': user,
            'PASSWORD': your_password,
    }
}.
```

This temporary creates db with different name and the conflict is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> Why could I be getting this error?

Because of insufficient permissions. You can alter the user permissions by `ALTER USER username CREATEDB;` after running `psql` with superuser priviliges.

Example,

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
psql (9.3.18)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# ALTER USER username CREATEDB;
ALTER ROLE
```