# How to use mutiple databases for django unitests?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, unit-testing

We, know how to use different databases for django testcases and development server. If not consult [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650509/different-db-for-testing-in-django).

Now my question is that? ***What if I have some test cases that can run in sqlite but some other test case(special) which will need postgres sql.
I want to specify it for those special test cases which have to be test on postgres.***

Now the question is why I test all of them in postgres?
***Testing in postgres is slower than sqlite3***, I guess experienced programmers know about this.

So is there a way to use different databases in unit tests?

I have found [this](http://django-ttdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package called Django Template Test Database(django-ttdb) but I guess it have support upto Django 1.7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to separate your tests into 2 distinct types:

- DB agnostic tests (sqlite3)
- Postgres tests

For the postgres specific tests you could isolate them in their own directory, (I like using a top level directory)

```
tests/
  integration/
    postgres/
```

Next the database connection settings should be exposed to the environment, either as environmental variables or through a separate settings file.  Then there would be two separate commands to run each distinct type of test:

`python manage.py test` to run all your django app tests
and `python manage.py test tests.integration.postgres` to run your postgres integration tests.  This is, of course, only one of many ways to handle your issue.