# Django testing can't find existing database table

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project and I want to make a test using `python manage.py test`, but I get this error:

```
 File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/
db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "ReservationsManagerApp_reservation" does not exist
```

The table does exist. In fact, the end-point that saves and retreives data from it works perfectly, and I can see the table en Postgres Admin tool.

The error only raises when running test.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Django tests run on a separate database that is created by your migrations just for the tests. If  they are faulty you will get this kind of problems.

Comment: Hi @KlausD., my answer and your comment did overlap somehow ;)

Comment: Thank you both. I deleted and created the migration files in order to avoid any problem with them, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Django uses an in-memory database for testing purposes as much I remember (SQLite).

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

and
[Different db for testing in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650509/different-db-for-testing-in-django)

So, if you look into your normal database, you might end having different tables than the testing setup (depending on your whole setup -- how you created the tables etc.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I have checked your answer and I found that **django** creates another database (`test_Intellibook`) when I run `manage.py test`, but it doesn't create the database objects, as the documentation says it should. The test works when I set test database to **sqlite**, but it doesn't when I set it to **Postgres**, and I want to use the latest one because I want to test database integrity also.