# Django tests are not running on a test database

Tags: django, database, testing

After running tests where I am creating rows in the database, I noticed that the current database is used instead of a test database like I think is the default behavior of django. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this behavior.

This is currently in the settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ["POSTGRES_NAME"],
        "USER": os.environ["POSTGRES_USER"],
        "PASSWORD": os.environ["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"],
        "HOST": os.environ["POSTGRES_HOST"],
        "PORT": os.environ["POSTGRES_PORT"],
    }
}
```

but when adding `"TEST": {"NAME": "test_database"},` it still seems to run on the main database.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ["POSTGRES_NAME"],
        "USER": os.environ["POSTGRES_USER"],
        "PASSWORD": os.environ["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"],
        "HOST": os.environ["POSTGRES_HOST"],
        "PORT": os.environ["POSTGRES_PORT"],
        "TEST": {
            "NAME": "test_database",
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get it so the tests write to a fresh test database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different db for testing in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650509/different-db-for-testing-in-django)

Comment: It doesn't because the accepted answer is from a much older version of django and the more recent answer which seems to work for people doesn't seem to work for me (I tried its fix and have shown that in the second code example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One critical step to get your tests to run on a test database is to use `TestCase` from `django.test`.

So this will run correctly.

```
from django.test import TestCase


class MyTests(TestCase):
    ...
```