# Django not creating a testdatabase when testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am running tests in my newly created Django project.

Normally I would expect to see a test database created for when tests are running. All tests are running fine, but I am seeing that my local database (for runserver use) is beeing used when running the tests.

A lot of excess data is beeing created in the wrong database. How can I get my test setup to use the normal test_*dabasename* setup again?

Im not sure what I have changed to make this happen and am totally stumped.

```
class TestRest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def test_allowed_to_get_list_authenticated(self):
        ....
```

Comment: please check this ticket it has similar answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650651/6365947

Comment: @issamabbas I can go in and edit the project.settings.test config with data like that, but then I get other errors, for example: 

DATABASES["default"] = {"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3", "NAME": "mydatabase"} leads to django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: base_user

and DATABASES["default"]["NAME"] = f"test_{os.getenv('DB_NAME')}" leads to database "test_mitt_se" does not exist

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it. Im such a bad programmer :(.

I imported from from

```
unittest.case import TestCase
```

when it should have been

```
from django.test import TestCase
```

This lead to no test database beeing created.