# How can I test unmanaged database in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing, django-models, multiple-databases

I'm working on a Django API that connects to an external database using unmanaged models. I want to create some objects in this database in my unit tests so I can test a few endpoints, but I cannot because this database is entirely unmanaged, there are no migrations at all for it. I have tried using the `schema_editor` to create the tables but it doesn't work because the schema doesn't exist. I have tried to run raw SQL to create the schema but it doesn't work. I have tried so many variations of so many different things that I honestly don't know which ones are worth describing here in detail. In my current setup I have a custom test runner that looks somewhat like this:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class TestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def setup_databases(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup_test_environment(*args, **kwargs)
        with connections["unmanaged_db"].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                """
                CREATE SCHEMA myschema;
                CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (
                    ...
                );
                """
            )
```

When I run my tests and try to create some objects in the DB using factories, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1247, in _fixture_teardown
    if self._should_check_constraints(connections[db_name]):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1255, in _should_check_constraints
    not connection.needs_rollback and connection.is_usable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 291, in is_usable
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 284, in _setup_and_call
    self._post_teardown()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1006, in _post_teardown
    self._fixture_teardown()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1250, in _fixture_teardown
    self._rollback_atomics(self.atomics)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1173, in _rollback_atomics
    transaction.set_rollback(True, using=db_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 92, in set_rollback
    return get_connection(using).set_rollback(rollback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 436, in set_rollback
    "The rollback flag doesn't work outside of an 'atomic' block.")
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: The rollback flag doesn't work outside of an 'atomic' block.
```

Is there a way I could fix this setup? Or is there perhaps an entirely different (and better) way of achieving this?

Comment: Haven't tried this, but what about copying your existing database, and using that copy as the test database? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650509/different-db-for-testing-in-django