# How to set up test db settings in a DRF project?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm running unit tests in a drf project with a mongo db and djongo connector. When I run tests one by one they compile successfully but when I run all of them with `python3 manage.py test test.path` they all fail except the first test. The following line from the logs indicates that there is an issue with dropping the test database.

```
FAILED SQL: DROP DATABASE "test_my_project_name"
```

Here's the database configuration.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'my_project_name',
        'CLIENT': {
           'host': os.environ[DB_HOST],
        }
    },
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_mytestdatabase',
        'USER': 'mytestdatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mytestpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to make the test db be used during tests and not the main db.
Also do I need to set up anything else for the testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During tests django use default config. Only difference is that before and after each test, it creates and destroys test db named after your default db with `test_` prefix.
Your error confirms that by saying it cannot drop `test_my_project_name` database - your default db name is `my_project_name` while your "test" db name is `test_mytestdatabase`.

You'll have to use different approach explained [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650651/12115512).

In short, you must use entirely different `DATABASES` config for testing:

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase'
    }
```

I would suggest storing that condition as one of the settings variables, for example

```
TEST_MODE = 'test' in sys.argv
```

and then you can use it for many things in runtime (logging, stubs, skip some validation, etc...)

Comment: It helped with running all tests but testing against a different db engine than what I'm using in production is tricky. For instance All the tests that were working previously are failing now.

Comment: This answer was helpful but I need to test in mongoDB, I'll post a follow up question.

Comment: This is the follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978645/testing-drf-project-with-a-mongodb

Comment: you were correct to post another question because that is different problem. I'm pretty sure you can't switch between mongo and postgre regardles of library you're using because they are completely different dbs, posgre being relational while mongo is document oriented, nosql. While djongo is providing some sort of abstraction, under the hood things are veeery different

Comment: You're right, that became obvious as soon as I ran tests with sqlite3.